# Uploading a file via SFTP from a raspberry pi to a remote server. From the command line

Tags: data-transfer

I need to upload files from a headless raspberry pi to a remote server.

A simpfied example:

The file to transfer 
/tmp/test.html

Remote location: something.com
Port 22
Username: user1
Password: pass:?word

Remote directory
/www/fileadmin/subdir/

I can access the remote location from windows using the WinSCP with the SFTP protocoll. Note: The real password contains a colon and questionmark just like in the example, which may cause extra problems.

What do I need to do to upload a file from raspbian/debian?

Comment: have you tried to make an `ssh` connection from your RPi to the remote server? Were you able to connect?

Answer (score 1):

`scp /tmp/test.html user1@something.com:/www/fileadmin/subdir/`

System will then prompt you for a password.

If you want this to work without a password prompt you'll need to set up [ssh key based authentication](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Public_Key_Authentication).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is, this is a remote service I have no control over, so switching to ssh key based authentification is not an option because I have to work with what's available.

Comment: @576i There is a tool called sshpass that you can install on RPi (apt-get/aptitude install sshpass) but I recommend against it. It is very bad habit to put ssh pasword anywhere else except your own head. Also check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp

Comment: @576i Typically if you can `ssh` to your host with a password then [`ssh-copy-id user1@something.com`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) should be able to set-up public key authentication on the host for you. Of course, you need to have prepared a password-less public key beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real **sftp server** on the remote side then you should be able to login and execute commands:

```
rpi ~$ sftp -P 22 user1@something.com   # you can omit default -P 22
user1@something.com's password:
Connected to something.com.
sftp> mkdir www/
sftp> mkdir www/fileadmin/
sftp> mkdir www/fileadmin/subdir/
sftp> cd www/fileadmin/subdir/

sftp> put /tmp/test.html
Uploading /tmp/test.html to /home/user1/www/fileadmin/subdir/test.html
/tmp/test.html                                100%   12    10.9KB/s   00:00

sftp> ls -l
-rw-r--r--    1 user1    user1          12 Jan 10 23:53 test.html
sftp> exit
rpi ~$
```

To upload the file in one batch you can execute:

```
rpi ~$ sftp user1@something.com:www/fileadmin/subdir/ <<< $'put /tmp/test.html'
user1@something.com's password:
Connected to something.com.
Changing to: /home/user1/www/fileadmin/subdir/
sftp> put /tmp/test.html
Uploading /tmp/test.html to /home/user1/www/fileadmin/subdir/test.html
/tmp/test.html                                100%   12    15.7KB/s   00:00
rpi ~$
```

The opposite for downloading is:

```
rpi ~$ sftp user1@something.com:www/fileadmin/subdir/test.html /tmp/test.html
user1@something.com's password:
Connected to something.com.
Fetching /home/user1/www/fileadmin/subdir/test.html to /tmp/test.html
/home/user1/www/fileadmin/subdir/test.html       100%   12     8.1KB/s   00:00
rpi ~$
```